# Docker: applications works fine via docker-compose up, but how to run it via Visual Studio and debug?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose

I have several projects and they must be running in seperate containers, and I have some shared library that should be buit also. I have found the following [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/stevelasker/2017/09/11/net-and-multistage-dockerfiles/) how to do it.
I will show the docker file for one project only, because they are pretty the same:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 AS builder
WORKDIR /src
COPY *.sln ./
COPY Web/Web.csproj Web/
RUN dotnet restore
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/Web
RUN dotnet build -c Debug -o /app

FROM builder AS publish
RUN dotnet publish -c Debug -o /app

FROM base AS production
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Web.dll"]
```

So, as you can see multi-stage building is used. if I use `docker-compose up` then all works fine. Next, I am trying to run it via Visual Studio, I see all steps in `Output` window, but in the end I get the following error:

> The target process exited without raising a CoreCLR started event.
>   Ensure that the target process is configured to use .NET Core. This
>   may be expected if the target process did not run on .NET Core. The
>   program '[13] dotnet' has exited with code 145 (0x91). The program ''
>   has exited with code 145 (0x91).

But how to debug the application now? This is the link to github [repo](https://github.com/SteveLasker/AspNetCoreMultiProject).

PS. For Tarun, default docker file that VS generates

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0
ARG source
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Web.dll"]
```

Comment: That is most probably because Visual studio has a additional compose file which is loaded. Check if they both are conflicting the run in your case. It would be `docker-compose.ci.build.yml`

Comment: @TarunLalwani. I tried to delete `...ci.build.yml` file, but nothing chagned

Comment: So if you don't use multistage dockerfile, it works?

Comment: @TarunLalwani I didn't change docker file itself. I just deleted the ci dockerfile. Moreover, I don't want to change the dockerfile in the question, because I want to build application in docker too. If I use simple dockerfile that Visual Studio generates when you create ASP.NET Core project from template, then debuging works fine.

Comment: Can you post the default Dockerfile also, would become easy to compare

Comment: @TarunLalwani added to the question, check please.

Comment: Can you change `FROM base AS production` to `FROM base` and see if it helps?

Comment: @TarunLalwani I don't see how it could affect because it's just the label. But, I tried, and it didn't help. This is the link to the repo https://github.com/SteveLasker/AspNetCoreMultiProject . If you want to take a closer look.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157854/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-user348173).

Comment: Quick Question, which version of Visual studio are you using?

Comment: So I assume you're on a Windows 10 pro machine using Docker for Windows? If so, are you using the latest version 17.10? Have you selected Linux containers? https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/#switch-between-windows-and-linux-containers And are you using Visual Studio Tools for Docker to run it? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/visual-studio-tools-for-docker

Comment: @ManoMarks yes, it's a Windows 10. The docker is last stable version: Version 17.09.0-ce-win33 (13620). Containers are Linux based. I use docker tools.

Comment: @TarunLalwani the last one, 15.4.2.

Comment: @user348173, another thing can you check in Docker setting if your C driver is shared? https://msdnshared.blob.core.windows.net/media/2016/06/d4w-shared-drives.png. I have a feeling that it may be a driver sharing issue

Comment: @TarunLalwani. yeah, all partitions are shared.... And, I can debug solution for default dockerfile that VS generates when you create project and check Enbale Docker. So, it's not setup/settings problem.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**TL;DR;**

So I installed VS 2017 and had a dig at this to understand what goes on here. After looking at the build process for your project I found below

> docker-compose  -f "C:\Users\tarlabs\Desktop\AspNetCoreMultiProject\docker-compose.yml" -f "C:\Users\tarlabs\Desktop\AspNetCoreMultiProject\docker-compose.override.yml" -f "C:\Users\tarlabs\Desktop\AspNetCoreMultiProject\obj\Docker\docker-compose.vs.debug.g.yml" -p dockercompose15184637154516733497 kill

**docker-compose.override.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
    ports:
      - "80"

  api:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
    ports:
      - "80"
```

Which is not much of interest.

**docker-compose.vs.debug.g.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:
  api:
    image: api:dev
    build:
      args:
        source: obj/Docker/empty/
    environment:
      - DOTNET_USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER=1
      - NUGET_FALLBACK_PACKAGES=/root/.nuget/fallbackpackages
    volumes:
      - C:\Users\tarlabs\Desktop\AspNetCoreMultiProject:/app
      - C:\Users\tarlabs\vsdbg:/remote_debugger:ro
      - C:\Users\tarlabs\.nuget\packages\:/root/.nuget/packages:ro
      - C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder:/root/.nuget/fallbackpackages:ro

    entrypoint: tail -f /dev/null
    labels:
      com.microsoft.visualstudio.debuggee.program: "dotnet"
      com.microsoft.visualstudio.debuggee.arguments: " --additionalProbingPath /root/.nuget/packages --additionalProbingPath /root/.nuget/fallbackpackages  bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0/Api.dll"
      com.microsoft.visualstudio.debuggee.workingdirectory: "/app"
      com.microsoft.visualstudio.debuggee.killprogram: "/bin/bash -c \"if PID=$$(pidof -x dotnet); then kill $$PID; fi\""

  web:
    image: web:dev
    build:
      args:
        source: obj/Docker/empty/
    environment:
      - DOTNET_USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER=1
      - NUGET_FALLBACK_PACKAGES=/root/.nuget/fallbackpackages
    volumes:
      - C:\Users\tarlabs\Desktop\AspNetCoreMultiProject:/app
      - C:\Users\tarlabs\vsdbg:/remote_debugger:ro
      - C:\Users\tarlabs\.nuget\packages\:/root/.nuget/packages:ro
      - C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder:/root/.nuget/fallbackpackages:ro

    entrypoint: tail -f /dev/null
    labels:
      com.microsoft.visualstudio.debuggee.program: "dotnet"
      com.microsoft.visualstudio.debuggee.arguments: " --additionalProbingPath /root/.nuget/packages --additionalProbingPath /root/.nuget/fallbackpackages  bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0/Web.dll"
      com.microsoft.visualstudio.debuggee.workingdirectory: "/app"
      com.microsoft.visualstudio.debuggee.killprogram: "/bin/bash -c \"if PID=$$(pidof -x dotnet); then kill $$PID; fi\""
```

Few interesting things

- The `ENTRYPOINT` we define won't make a difference during debugging as it overridden by VS with `tail -f /dev/null`
- The `com.microsoft.visualstudio.debuggee.arguments` has a value with path `bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0/Web.dll`
- The working directory for debugging is always set to `/app` using `com.microsoft.visualstudio.debuggee.workingdirectory`
- Volume mount `C:\Users\tarlabs\Desktop\AspNetCoreMultiProject:/app`

Looking at Volume mount `C:\Users\tarlabs\Desktop\AspNetCoreMultiProject:/app`, I was like Wow! Anything that you have in your `/app` folder in your Dockerfile, will be just overridden by that mount. So whether you build and put the files inside that or you don't do anything won't make a difference.

Now I went inside the container and realized that the `Web.dll` is insider `/app/Web/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0/Web.dll` but the debugger is expecting it to be on `/app/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0/Web.dll`. After looking in every setting I could not find this path anywhere.

Then I played around with a new project. Adding one project with Docker support and later adding another project with docker support. This gave me a hint as the `docker-compose.yml` was

```
version: '3'

services:
  webapplication1:
    image: webapplication1
    build:
      context: ./WebApplication1
      dockerfile:Dockerfile

  webapplication2:
    image: webapplication2
    build:
      context: ./../WebApplication2
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

This gave me a hint that the dynamic `docker-compose.vs.debug.g.yml` file takes the volume mount based on the context given in your `docker-compose.yml`. Now looking at your project.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    image: web
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Web/Dockerfile

  api:
    image:api
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Api/Dockerfile
```

Since the context is `.` the Volume mount is generated as

```
- C:\Users\tarlabs\Desktop\AspNetCoreMultiProject:/app
```

To correct that we update our `docker-compose.yml` to

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    image: web
    build:
      context: ./Web
      dockerfile: Dockerfile

  api:
    image:api
    build:
      context: ./Api
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

Next our Dockerfile was doing too many things which VS debugger kind of just ignores. So you just needs 2 lines in your `Dockerfile` for debugging to actually work

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
```

Rest anything that you did was just thrown away by the volume mount. So no point in doing that for debugging. You can use multistage build approach for deploying to production but not for debugging. After making those two changes in your project debugging started working for me

[image: Debugging Working]

Comment: You can define a custom `entrypoint` in a new file `docker-compose.vs.debug.yml`. This one does not get overriden. More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/docker-compose-properties?view=vs-2022#customize-the-app-startup-process

Answer (score 6):

Had the same issue because of a Sharp Symbol (`#`) in my project path (Like in C#... like `C:\Project\C#\MyProject\`).

Removed the sharp symbol from the path (`C:\Project\C-sharp\MyProject\`) and I was good to go.

Comment: I can't believe I spent half a day fighting with this issue only to come up to your unpopular answer and see that in fact this was my issue. You made my day! Congrats!

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue building .Net 2.0 App for Linux. Tried all the steps above and it didn't help. The issue for me was that I had used spaces in csproj file names and project directories.

When I removed the spaces it fixed the issue. I tried creating a .Net Core Application called "WebApplication 1" and it also failed so seems like a bug in VS tooling or the docker file/compose files it creates.

Comment: In my case (boot2docker in VurtualBox on Windows 10), the missing piece was sharing relevant folders with the docker host. Without it, mounted folders appeared empty in the container. Once I set these in VirtualBox settings (machine settings -> shared folders -> machine folders), it started working.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar situation with our .NET Core 3.0 project when tried to add docker-compose support to the solution. Although the Dockerfiles and the docker-compose.yml were setup according to the MSDN blogpost and using the docker-compose binary in PowerShell was working as expected, debugging the docker-compose project from Visual Studio always failed with the above error message.

As none of the proposals in the accepted answer worked for us we had to look for another solution. In our case we had to make sure that

1. The same .NET Core 3.0 SDK preview version is used in the Dockerfile as is installed on the Visual Studio host

Our Dockerfiles were configured to use .NET Core 3.0 preview 4 while we already updated the development workstations to .NET Core preview 5. Downgrading the development worksations to .NET Core preview 4 or using preview 5 in the Dockerfiles helped.

2. The output directory for the Debug configuration of the dockerized projects is within the project directory

If the output directory is outside the project directory (e.g. ....\bin) the remote debugger in the docker image is started with this relative path to the binary. But Visual Studio mounts the project directory as the /app directory into the container no matter which context is set in the docker-compose.yml. If the output directory is outside the project directory the binaries are not available in the docker container.

3. Location of the build instructions of your dockerized projects

TL;DR: Place the instructions to build the docker image in either docker-compose.yml or docker-compose.override.yml

We have three docker-compose files: 
 - docker-compose.yml: networking, services, image names, volumes, environment
 - docker-compose.override.yml: additional exposed ports for direct access to internal services
 - docker-compose.ci-build.yml: instruction to build the Docker images.

For deployment to test and QA environments just docker-compose.yml is used. Docker-compose.yml and docker-compose.override.yml are used by developers to startup the whole application locally with access to internal services. Docker-compose.yml and Docker-compose.ci-build.yml

So the instructions to build the docker images are neither in docker-compose.yml nor in docker-compose.override.yml. Visual Studio seems to ignore all files added to the docker-compose projects and just processes docker-compose.yml and docker-compose.override.yml. Without build instructions Visual Studio just runs docker-compose up and never enters debugging state.

With build instructions in docker-compose.yml or docker-compose.override.yml Visual Studio generates additional docker-compose files on \obj\Docker: docker-compose.vs.debug.g.yml and docker-compose.vs.debug.partial.g.yml. These files are contain the build instructions for the debug images and you will be able to debug your dockerized projects.

4. Paths in docker-compose and Dockerfile
   You should also be aware that changing the context in the docker-compose.yml might require changes to the Dockerfile of the project. The paths in the Dockerfile are relative to the context and relative not to the Dockerfile. Changing the context in the docker-compose.yml might break these relative paths.