# Why does the ASP.NET Core Multi-Stage Dockerfile use 4 Stages

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, dockerfile, docker-multi-stage-build

This is the default multi-stage Dockerfile when you click on 'Add Docker Support' in Visual Studio on an ASP.NET Core site.

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY WebApplication1.sln ./
COPY WebApplication1/WebApplication1.csproj WebApplication1/
RUN dotnet restore
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/WebApplication1
RUN dotnet build -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApplication1.dll"]
```

Why have they chosen to use four stages, starting and finishing with the `base` stage. Also, why create a `publish` stage using the same `build` base image. Why does the Dockerfile not look like this with three stages:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY WebApplication1.sln ./
COPY WebApplication1/WebApplication1.csproj WebApplication1/
RUN dotnet restore
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/WebApplication1
RUN dotnet build -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app

FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0 AS final
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApplication1.dll"]
```

Is there some advantage to this that I am missing?

Comment: perhaps, smaller image size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file effectively equivalent to below

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY WebApplication1.sln ./
COPY WebApplication1/WebApplication1.csproj WebApplication1/
RUN dotnet restore
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/WebApplication1
RUN dotnet build -c Release -o /app
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app

FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0 AS base
EXPOSE 80
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApplication1.dll"]
```

Now the reason they may have chosen 4 build stage might be any of the two

- Presentational
- Future changes

So it may be that it depicts a

```
base -> build -> publish -> deploy the build
```

The size with 2 build stage would also the same as this one. So there is no obvious difference between the 2 stage and the 4 stage. It becomes a matter preference,  representation and all. Nothing technologically different

Comment: I wrote a very similar Dockerfile to yours, then realized, that the `dotnet build` and `dotnet publish` commands are being output to the same folder. Does the 3 stage Dockerfile in my question stop that?

Comment: No it doesn't, it still the same output. 
 See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27320374/the-difference-between-build-and-publish-in-vs. I have not checked if `build` and `publish` create different files but just a `publish` also should have a worked as per the OS thread, because if it the build is not done then `publish` will also build.

Comment: Yes, I thought that too. I'm assuming that `build` is in there so you can add a command to run tests. Probably the best solution is to remove the output argument from the `build` command, so the binaries are built to the default `bin/Release` directory.

Comment: Read this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46949192/docker-applications-works-fine-via-docker-compose-up-but-how-to-run-it-via-vis/47095754#47095754 and you will find that VS doesn't have the most optimized docker files. But you want to use what VS generates, so that it integrates well with the future upgrades

Answer (score 2):

There is no programatic reason for using 4 stages.

In the first stage just configuration is changed. In the third stage the image is not changed. The only use of `FROM build AS publish` to have a new alias.

I think there is no use of taking care of later changes in the build structure of docker. (The 4 stage code probably does that.) Use versioned images, just like in your example. E.g. `2.0` instead of `latest`. This way incomatibility can be avoided. If there will be changes in the way of the build, you can catch up with it.

The [docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/dotnetcore/#prerequisites) recommendation works with no csproj name specified, as using `*.csproj`. That works for most of the projects, producing about 350MB image-size.